# Pycharm terminal looking wierd

Tags: terminal, pycharm

In Pycharm terminal when I type `git branch` all branches are listed as usual but then there is a colon which I need to press enter to be able to type new command. Does anyone know how to get rid of the colon?

[image]

or sometimes when I hit ENTER it stuck:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is normal behavior: Git uses a pager (for example less) to output all your branches. To display your output without such pager, use `git -P branch`.

From the [git man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/git.1.html):

> ```
>    -p, --paginate
>        Pipe all output into less (or if set, $PAGER) if standard
>        output is a terminal. This overrides the pager.<cmd>
>        configuration options (see the "Configuration Mechanism"
>        section below).
>
>    -P, --no-pager
>        Do not pipe Git output into a pager.
> ```